# Object Required error message with IE only

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, object, loading

so in IE im getting an error at the bottom of my page saying "Object Required" on a certain line. The page loads ok but I dont want this error. Its only in IE but I dont know how to fix it.

The line in question is just a "?>"

the code within the PHP tags is just:

```
<?php
include('http://cdn.lektronix.net/new_site/home_slides/' . $content_location . '/content.html')
?>
```

and the code within that include is:

```
<?php
//CONTENT OF THE HOME PAGE ROTATING BANNER FOR THE UK 

//To display more or less slides just add or remove them. There is no need to update the jqbanner.js script.

//The css for each file is contained in style.css in this directory
?>

    <div class="jqb_slide" id = "power" title="">
        <div id = "slide_1_content">
            <h1>Lektronix</h1>
            <p><?=get_content(3232)?></p>
            <div class = "quote_btn">
                <a href = "general_enquiry"><?=get_content(3233)?></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="jqb_slide" id = "web" title="" >
        <div id = "slide_3_content">
            <h1><?=get_content(2045)?></h1>
            <p><?=get_content(2046)?></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="jqb_slide" id = "pcb" title="">
        <div id = "slide_4_content">
            <h1><?=get_content(3740)?></h1>
            <p><?=get_content(3741)?></p>
            <div class = "quote_btn">
                <a href = "repair_enquiry"><?=get_content(3233)?></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="jqb_slide" id = "stock" title="">
        <div id = "slide_5_content">
            <h1><?=get_content(3349)?></h1>
            <div id = "repair_quote">
                <a href = "<?=$myroot?>obsolete_and_refurbished"><?=ucwords(get_content(3338))?></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="jqb_slide" id = "robot" title="">
        <div id = "header_block">
            <div id = "header_block_body">
                <h1><?=get_content(3779)?></h1>
            </div>
            <div id = "header_block_bottom"></div>
            <div id = "repair_quote">
            <a href = "<?=$myroot?>robots"><?=ucwords(get_content(3338))?></a>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div id = "slide_6_content">
            <p><?=get_content(3789)?></p>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Checked a number of browsers its just IE, and I cant see a problem with the code

here is the rendered page source

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Electrical Engineering | Electronic Repairs | Lektronix India</title>
<meta name = "description" content = "Electrical engineering, electronic repairs, automation spares, refurbishment and obsolete equipment from Lektronix, the world&rsquo;s leading provider to the automation industry." />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "http://cdn.lektronix.net/new_site/style/main.css?1363776103" />
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "http://cdn.lektronix.net/new_site/style/jqbanner.css?1356002329" />
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "http://cdn.lektronix.net/new_site/home_slides/uk/style.css?1360065818" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.lektronix.net/new_site/script/jqbanner.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
window.onload = function(){
  if(!document.getElementById) return;
  document.getElementById('language_submit_header').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('language_submit_footer').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('contact_branch_select_submit').style.display='none';
}
// -->
</script>
</head>
<body>


<div id = "main_wrapper">

    <div id = "header">
        <div id = "header_top">
                        <div id = "blue_bar">
                <div id = "blue_bar_left"></div>
                <div id = "blue_bar_content">
                    <div class = "blue_bar_item">
                        <img src = "http://cdn.lektronix.net/new_site/images/job-track.png" alt = "Online Job Tracking" /><span class = "top_v_align"><a href = "account">Online Job Tracking</a></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "blue_bar_item">
                        <img src = "http://cdn.lektronix.net/new_site/images/phone.png" alt = "Telephone Number" /> <span class = "top_v_align">+91 213 5677800</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "blue_bar_item">
                        <img src = "http://cdn.lektronix.net/new_site/images/email.png" alt = "Email Address" /> <span class = "top_v_align"><a href = "mailto:sales.india@lektronix.in">sales.india@lektronix.in</a></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "blue_bar_item">
                                            <form id = "language_form" action = "language_set" method="post" >
<select name = "lang" id = "language_select" onchange = "this.form.submit()">
<option value = "15">中文 (Chinese)</option>
<option value = "11">Český (Czech)</option>
<option selected = "selected" value = "1">English (UK)</option>
<option value = "16">English (US)</option>
<option value = "3">Français (French)</option>
<option value = "2">Deutsch (German)</option>
<option value = "4">Italiano (Italian)</option>
<option value = "6">Polski (Polish)</option>
<option value = "12">Português (Portuguese)</option>
<option value = "8">Русский (Russian)</option>
<option value = "14">Slovenský (Slovakian)</option>
<option value = "5">Español (Spanish)</option>
</select>
<!--[if IE]>
<input type = "submit" value = "Update" id = "language_submit_header"/>
<![endif]-->
</form>
                    </div>  
                </div>
                <div id = "blue_bar_right"></div>
            </div>          
        </div>
        <div id = "header_bottom">
            <div id = "header_right">

                <div id = "search">

                    <form action = "query" method = "POST" id = "search_form">
                        <button type = "submit" name = "search_button" id = "search_button"></button>
                        <input name = "search_box" id = "search_box" type = "text" value = "Enter Part Number or Manufacturer" onClick = "this.value=''" />

                    </form>

                </div>
                <div id = "navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href = "index">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href = "about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href = "products">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href = "media">Media</a></li>
        <li><a href = "contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href = "help">Help</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>          </div>
            <div id = "header_left">
                <a href = "index"><img src = "http://cdn.lektronix.net/new_site/images/header_logo.png" alt = "Lektronix, A Rockwell Automation Business" id = "logo" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id = "thin_blue_bar"></div>

    <div id = "content">
    <div id = "breadcrumbs">
<ul>
<li class = "home_crumb"><b>Home</b></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id = "rotating_banner">
<div id="jqb_object">

    <div class="jqb_slides">

        <div class="jqb_slide" id = "power" title="">
            <div id = "slide_1_content">
                <h1>Lektronix</h1>
                <p>Lektronix can help with your Industrial Automation needs no matter what industry you're in. Contact us today for a free quote on new and refurbished spares, repairs and service exchange</p>
                <div class = "quote_btn">
                    <a href = "general_enquiry">Get a Free Quote</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="jqb_slide" id = "web" title="" >
            <div id = "slide_3_content">
                <h1>We've Updated Our Website!</h1>
                <p>Please look around the new and improved website and be sure to update your bookmarks.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="jqb_slide" id = "pcb" title="">
            <div id = "slide_4_content">
                <h1>Industrial Automation Repairs</h1>
                <p>Save money with Lektronix. We offer repairs on the full range of industrial automation products from all leading manufacturers. </p>
                <div class = "quote_btn">
                    <a href = "repair_enquiry">Get a Free Quote</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="jqb_slide" id = "stock" title="">
            <div id = "slide_5_content">
                <h1>Over 17,000 Obsolete and Refurbished Parts in Stock</h1>
                <div id = "repair_quote">
                    <a href = "obsolete_and_refurbished">More Information</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="jqb_slide" id = "robot" title="">
            <div id = "header_block">
                <div id = "header_block_body">
                    <h1>Robotic Repairs and Spares at LeKtroniX</h1>
                </div>
                <div id = "header_block_bottom"></div>
                <div id = "repair_quote">
                <a href = "robots">More Information</a>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div id = "slide_6_content">
                <p>Trust LeKtroniX to get your robot up and running quickly and efficiently, whatever the problem.
<br></p>
            </div>

        </div>  


    </div>

    <div class="jqb_bar">
        <div class="jqb_info"></div>
        <div id="btn_next" class="jqb_btn jqb_btn_next"></div>
        <div id="btn_pauseplay" class="jqb_btn jqb_btn_pause"></div>
        <div id="btn_prev" class="jqb_btn jqb_btn_prev"></div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
<div id = "home_boxes">

        <div id="newsletter_box">
            <div class = "box_content">
                <h2>Newsletter</h2>
                <p>Sign up to our FREE newsletter to ensure you never miss out on our fantastic offers!</p>
                <form action = "newsletter_process.php" method = "post">
                    <input type = "text" name = "email" class = "news_signup_input" value = Email Address onClick = "this.value=''" />
                    <input type = "submit" name = "newsletter_submit" value = "" class = "news_signup_submit" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>


    <div id = "contact_box">
        <div class = "box_content">
            <a href = "contact"><h2>Contact Us</h2></a>
            <p>Lektronix are an international company with branches worldwide. Click here to get in touch with your local branch</p>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div id = "about_box">
        <div class = "box_content">
            <a href = "about"><h2>About Us</h2></a>
            <p>Find out why you should use Lektronix to supply or repair your automation equipment</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class = "float_break"></div>

</div><div class = "float_break"></div>
<div id = "two_boxes">
    <div id = "repair_box">
        <h2>Need A Repair?</h2>
        <p><b>Get a free repair quotation!</b></p>
        <p class = "repair_first">We have built test rigs to ensure that your part is fully repaired</p>
        <p class = "repair_second">All repairs come with a 12 month free warranty</p>
        <a href = "repair_enquiry"><h3>Contact us today for a free repair quote</h3></a>
    </div>
    <div id = "siemens_box">
        <h2>Siemens</h2>
        <p class = "siemens_first"><b>Lektronix have a wide range of Siemens spares in stock.</b></p>
        <p class = "siemens_second">Lektronix Repair and Support the whole range of Siemens S5 and S7 equipment including OP HMI Screens and PG Programmers. </p>
        <a href = "products/siemens/2512/null/0/1"><h3>View our full Siemens range</h3></a>
    </div>
</div>
<!--Free Repair Collection -->
<!--<style type = "text/css" media = "screen">
    #uk_repair_collect { width: 1000px; height: 198px; padding: 6px; background: URL('images/hp-repair-collection.jpg'); margin: 20px auto 20px auto; overflow: hidden; }
    #uk_repair_collect h2 { font-size:12pt; margin: 0 0 5px 5px; padding: 0;}
    #uk_repair_collect h3 { font-size:10pt; margin: 0 0 5px 5px; padding: 0;}
    #uk_repair_collect p { color: #333333;}
    #uk_repair_collect .steps { width: 130px; float: left; text-align: center; margin: 13px 20px 0 170px; padding: 0; _margin: 13px 30px 0 90px; }
    #uk_repair_collect .firststep { width: 140px; float: left; text-align: center; margin: 25px 10px 0 100px; padding: 0; _margin: 30px 30px 0 45px; }
    #uk_repair_collect .link { margin: 105px 0 0 600px; clear: both; width:430px; *margin: 25px 0 0 430px; padding: 0; }
    #uk_repair_collect .title { margin: 15px 0 10px 5px; padding: 0;}
</style>

    <div id = "uk_repair_collect">
        <h2>Free Repair Collection and Evaluation Service</h2>
        <h3>Do you have a faulty part that needs repairing? Lektronix will pick up your part and repair it.</h3>
        <p class = "title"><b>Get your faulty part repaired in 3 simple steps:</b></p>
        <p class = "firststep"><a href = "general_enquiry"><b>1. Send an enquiry</b></a></p>
        <p class = "steps"><b>2. We'll arrange to collect your part for free </b></p>
        <p class = "steps"><b>3. Lektronix will fix and return your part to you</b></p>
        <p class = "link">Learn more about our <a href = "repair-collection"><b>FREE Repair Collection Service</b></a></p>
    </div>-->
<!-- end of repair -->
    </div>
</div>
<div class = "float_break"></div>
<div id = "footer">
    <div id = "robot_wrapper">
        <div id = "footer_wrapper">
            <div id = "footer_columns">
                <div class = "footer_column">
                    <h4>Lektronix</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href = "about/lektronix_group/1">Group Overview</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "about/new_equipment/3">New Equipment</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "about/refurbished_equipment/4">Refurbished Equipment</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "about/index.php?helpid=6">Repairs</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "about/awards/5">Awards</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "site_map">Site Map</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class = "footer_column">
                    <h4>Buy Stock</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href = "products/siemens/2512/null/0/1">Siemens</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "products/control_techniques/523/null/0/1">Control Techniques</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "products/bosch/313/null/0/1">Bosch</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "products/fanuc/948/null/0/1">Fanuc</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "products/indramat/1303/null/0/1">Indramat</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "products/telemecanique/2768/null/0/1">Telemecanique</a></li>
                        <li><b><a href = "products/manufacturers">Manufacturers A-Z</a></b></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class = "footer_column">
                    <h4>Customer Services</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href = "contact">Contact Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "feedback">Feedback</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "help/policies/4#cookie_policy">Cookie Policy</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "help/policies/4#privacy_policy">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "help/policies/4#terms_and_conditions">Promotional Terms & Conditions</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "account"><b>Online Job Tracking</b></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class = "footer_column" id = "four">
                    <h4>Other Branches</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href = "http://www.lektronix.sa.com" target = "_blank">Saudi Arabia</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "http://www.lektronix.co.za" target = "_blank">South Africa</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "http://www.lektronix.pt" target = "_blank">Portugal</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "http://www.lektronix.es" target = "_blank">Spain</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "http://www.lektronix.us" target = "_blank">USA</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "http://www.lektronix.mx" target = "_blank">Mexico</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class = "footer_column_last">
                    <h4>Contact</h4>
                    <p class = "center">+91 213 5677800<br /><a href = "mailto:sales.india@lektronix.in">sales.india@lektronix.in</a></p>
                                        <form id = "language_form" action = "language_set" method="post" >
<select name = "lang" id = "language_select" onchange = "this.form.submit()">
<option value = "15">中文 (Chinese)</option>
<option value = "11">Český (Czech)</option>
<option selected = "selected" value = "1">English (UK)</option>
<option value = "16">English (US)</option>
<option value = "3">Français (French)</option>
<option value = "2">Deutsch (German)</option>
<option value = "4">Italiano (Italian)</option>
<option value = "6">Polski (Polish)</option>
<option value = "12">Português (Portuguese)</option>
<option value = "8">Русский (Russian)</option>
<option value = "14">Slovenský (Slovakian)</option>
<option value = "5">Español (Spanish)</option>
</select>
<!--[if IE]>
<input type = "submit" value = "Update" id = "language_submit_footer"/>
<![endif]-->
</form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "float_break"></div>
            <div id = "footer_address">
                <p class = "center">131, Functional Industrial Estate, Patparganj, Delhi, India 110092<br />
                VAT No. TIN: 2757032 | Company No. U31200DL1991PTC045425
 | Registered in India<br />
                &copy; 2002 - 2013 Rockwell Automation Limited</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it the missing semi colon at the end of the PHP line?

Comment: As this is browser specific and seems JavaScript related, can you provide the source of the rendered page?

Comment: @mattytommo, semi-colon before closing PHP tag is optional.

Comment: actually yes it was missing the semi-colon. But I've just fixed that and the error message is still showing :(

Comment: @VangaSasidhar I thought that might have been the case, was worth a suggestion I guess :)

Comment: ive added the page source for you to see

Comment: don't look at the line numbers in the PHP code when you get errors in the browser; look at the line number in the HTML code that the browser sees. Use 'view source' to see that.

Comment: Also, this might or might not be relevant, but in the example you've given, your `<DOCTYPE>` has spaces in front of it. This is invalid: The DOCTPYE must be the *very* first thing on the page; no spaces, no comments. Having spaces there will cause IE to ignore the doctype and drop into quirks mode. You don't want that.

Comment: SDC...Thankyou, Because I wasnt looking in the source code I was looking in the wrong place. Ive found the problem following your advice :) thanks again much appreciated, you should have put that as an answer so I could give you some rep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a piece of javascript calling things that were not there, The reason the problem couldnt be seen was because I was looking in the wrong place. I was looking at the code in my files rather than the source code for the page. This lead me to the wrong place but as soon as i looked at the source code I found the dodgy javascript. Thanks to SDC for pointing this out to me